# Serilog logger is not logging when method is called from Lambda Function

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, serilog

I'm using serilog for logging purpose. I have a AWS lambda function in a project which logs the data to a cloudwatch group `lambda_logs`. I also have a method `oflline_method()` in another project which by default logs the data to a cloudwatch group `offline_logs`. `oflline_method()` method is being called by the lambda internally in some scenario. In this case all the logs related to lambda needed be logged into `lambda_logs` group and logs related to `offline_method` needed to be logged into `offline_logs`. But the logs written from `offline_method` are not logged into cloudwatch group only when it's called by lambda.

```
namespace Online
{
    public class lambda
    {
        public async Task<KinesisFirehoseResponse> MethodA(ILambdaContext context)
        {
            //this will be logged into lambda_logs
            context.Logger.LogLine("Logged by the method MethodA in lambda");

            var firehoseResponse = new KinesisFirehoseResponse();

            //Calls the oflline_method from offline project 
            var a = oflline_method();

            return firehoseResponse;
        }
    }
}


namespace OfflineProject
{
    public class Offline
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Offline> _logger;

        public Offline()
        {
            _logger = new SerilogLoggerFactory().CreateLogger<Offline>();
        }

        public string oflline_method()
        {
            //this should be logged into offline_logs, but it is not happening only when called by lambda
            _logger.LogInformation(" Logged by the method oflline_method in offline");

            return "from offline";

        }
    }
}
```

Dependency injection is used for creating logger object. Below is the configs in Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    var options = new CloudWatchSinkOptions
    {
        LogGroupName = "offline_logs",
        TextFormatter = new LogFormatter(),
        MinimumLogEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Verbose,
        BatchSizeLimit = 100,
        QueueSizeLimit = 10000,
        Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
        CreateLogGroup = true,
        LogStreamNameProvider = new AwsCloudWatchLogStream(),
        RetryAttempts = 5
    };

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(new EnvironmentVariableLoggingLevelSwitch(DebugMode))
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .WriteTo.AmazonCloudWatch(options, new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient())
        .CreateLogger();
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you solve this question? the same problem is happening to me